# Sigabrt when iterating an array pointer in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I wrote this C code to add a list of Fibonacci numbers dynamically to an array. The calculation and assignment works just fine. but when trying to print the values i am getting a segment fault error.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int num;
    int* nums; 

    scanf("%d", &num);
    nums = (int *) calloc(num, sizeof(int));
    nums[0] = 0;
    nums[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
        nums[i] = nums[i - 2]  + nums[i - 1];   
    }

    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf(" %d ", nums[i]); //seg fault here (line 19 of main.c)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Backtrace from GDB

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:49
#1  0x00007ffff7de4864 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7e5020a in __malloc_assert (
    assertion=assertion@entry=0x7ffff7f6f338 "(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)", file=file@entry=0x7ffff7f6acdf "malloc.c", line=line@entry=2539, function=function@entry=0x7ffff7f6fbd0 <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.3> "sysmalloc") at malloc.c:303
#3  0x00007ffff7e52914 in sysmalloc (nb=nb@entry=1040, av=av@entry=0x7ffff7f9eba0 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:2539
#4  0x00007ffff7e5376f in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7f9eba0 <main_arena>, bytes=bytes@entry=1024) at malloc.c:4366
#5  0x00007ffff7e551a4 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=bytes@entry=1024) at malloc.c:3229
#6  0x00007ffff7e3c2d4 in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x7ffff7f9f6c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at filedoalloc.c:101
#7  0x00007ffff7e4c030 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff7f9f6c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at libioP.h:948
#8  0x00007ffff7e4b0c0 in _IO_new_file_overflow (f=0x7ffff7f9f6c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, ch=-1) at fileops.c:745
#9  0x00007ffff7e49815 in _IO_new_file_xsputn (n=1, data=<optimized out>, f=<optimized out>) at libioP.h:948
#10 _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x7ffff7f9f6c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=<optimized out>, n=1) at fileops.c:1197
#11 0x00007ffff7e32406 in outstring_func (done=0, length=1, string=0x555555556007 " %d ", s=0x7ffff7f9f6c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>) at ../libio/libioP.h:948
#12 __vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7f9f6c0 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=0x555555556007 " %d ", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffdee0, mode_flags=mode_flags@entry=0) at vfprintf-internal.c:1404
#13 0x00007ffff7e1d70f in __printf (format=<optimized out>) at printf.c:33
#14 0x000055555555529c in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe0e8) at main.c:19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
 for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
```

has an off by one error. Change the `<=` to `<`. Gdb detected the error and used `SIGABRT` to terminate the process.

Comment: thanks it worked by i am curious as to why the SIGABRT happened when trying to print the values instead of trying to assign the value

Comment: The buffer overrun is detected by the next malloc, which in this case occurs when the printf is run. If another malloc does not occur, the buffer overrun will not be detected.